# Every time I press Crtl+f, Xterm opens despite not being a global keybind; how can I disable this behaviour?

Tags: find, keyboard-shortcuts, kde, manjaro, xterm

I think some programs use xterm, so I don't want to uninstall it, but I use bash and Konsole for my terminal, so I don't need it bound to a key, especially Ctrl+f as it makes performing searches extremely annoying.  The weird thing is it isn't listed in Global Shortcuts or Custom shortcuts.  In Standard Shortcuts Ctrl+f appears to be bound to "find" which I think is the desired behaviour, yet every time I press Ctrl+f it fails to start the find operation and opens xterm.  I am running KDE on Manjaro, and can provide a debug/log if you tell me what to do/where to find it.

Comment: What about files such as `~/.xbindkeysrc`? Does that exist? If so, is the shortcut defined there?

Comment: @Peschke Yes!  Thank you!  It seems to be an example in the file that it generated!  I don't know why they would rebind that by default.  If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if `~/.xbindkeysrc` exists and has a reference to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Key binds in that file are independent from the window manager and desktop environment, and will take precedence.